# Does reloading a WebView cancel former calls to setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, android, battery

This might be a stupid question, I cannot find the answer though:

I am animating some shapes in a HTML/JS page displayed by an Android `WebView`. To do so I use the Javascript `setInterval()` method:

```
var animateThreadHandler;

function animateThread() {
   // animate some stuff here...
}

// This function is called from the HTML page: <body onload="onBodyLoaded()">
function onBodyLoaded() {
    animateThreadHandler = setInterval(animateThread, 200);
}
```

Later, in the code of my Android `Activity` this time, I switch from this HTML page to another one, keeping the same `WebView`:

```
mWebview.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, htmlContent, HTML_CONTENT_TYPE, HTML_ENCODING, null);
```

But I never call `clearInterval(animateThreadHandler)` from the Javascript. Even though this works well, I wouldn't like to drain the user's battery by doing useless Javascript function calls that would end up in errors that I couldn't see.

I monitored the behaviour of the JS `animateThread()` function by making it to produce logs (see comments), and the logging stops once the `WebView` is reloaded. But this doesn't prove the scheduler is cleared: calls to `animateThread()` may keep occurring - and silentely failing as the JS code was unloaded at `Webview` reload time.

The rationales behind this doubt reside in what the [W3School says](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

> The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until
>   clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

I neither call `clearInterval()` nor I "close" the window (I'm just reloading it), so I am really not sure of the underlying behaviour of my code. Any idea?

Comment: Can you put some code in your interval that outputs a log message, or otherwise does something you'd be able to see, that is *not* dependent on a piece of UI? Then you could see if it continues to fire after the page changes. My guess is it would not.

Comment: @murdock Thanks for the heads-up. I did (I binded a JS call from `animateThread()`to a Java method that does a `Log.d()`), and as expected the logging stops at `Webview` reload time. But this doesn't mean the scheduler is cleared: there might be calls to `animateThread()` that keep occuring and that fail as  `animateThread()` and the rest of the JS code was unloaded when reloading the `WebView`. This is actually what I'm trying to figure out.